# Didn't G'd answer Moses?

Tags: exodus

I wondered if I have been reading something wrong, but as in english and in my native tongue, it seems the translation is identical. I comes from **Exodus 3:11** in:

> But Moses said to God, "Who am I, that I should go to Pharaoh and
> bring the Israelites out of Egypt?" (MIT)

And He (God) continued:

> And God said, "I will be with you. And this will be the sign to you
> that it is I who have sent you: When you have brought the people out
> of Egypt, you will worship God on this mountain."

And in hebrew:

> ## וַיֹּ֤אמֶר מֹשֶׁה֙ אֶל־הָ֣אֱלֹהִ֔ים מִ֣י אָנֹ֔כִי כִּ֥י אֵלֵ֖ךְ
>
> ## אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה וְכִ֥י אוֹצִ֛יא אֶת־בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל מִמִּצְרָֽיִם׃

(source: sefaria)

Is there something that I am missing? Did G'd respond Moses, and if so what is the answer?

Comment: It is a rhetorical question, meaning he doesn't feel worthy to talk to Pharaoh, because he is a nobody, he feels hesitant and weak, nervous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, God answered, though His answer may not have been what Moses was looking for.

- God asked Moses to go deliver Israel
- Moses suggests his own inadequacy
- God responds by teaching Moses that this is irrelevant because He (God) will be with Moses.

Moses on his own does not have the power to free Israel. God does. In the following chapter (see Ex. 4:10-16) Moses will again suggest his own inadequacy, and be reprimanded by the Lord for not a) having greater trust in God's ability to fulfil His promises & b) utilizing the tools (such as his gifted brother) God has provided.

Comment: Quite right!! +1.

Answer (score 0):

**"Did G'd respond Moses, and if so what is the answer?"**
Yes. God's response to Moses regarding Moses's identity is, essentially, that Moses is to be identified by his relationship with God. God basically answers that Moses is: 1). The one that God is with, and 2).  The one who has been sent by God and thus the one who represents God's holy will.

God's response also indicates that Moses's identity, like God's own identity, would be progressively revealed to all as the narrative develops and Moses accomplishes the sacred tasks that God has set out before him and has empowered him to do.

> And God said, "I will be with you. And this will be the sign to you that it is I who have sent you: When you have brought the people out of Egypt, you will worship God on this mountain." - Exodus 3:12